# Outputting 4k@60hz from HP 15-as152nr laptop

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi, intel-graphics

I have thinked this in any way, I cannot figure out a solution on how to output on an external monitor (which can be anyone, really, not budget tied) at `4k@60hz`.

The laptop got `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` installed, with latest Intel drivers :

```
➜ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:126 mémoire:b0000000-b0ffffff mémoire:a0000000-afffffff portE/S:3000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

*xrandr output*

```
➜ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 3560, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  40.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 connected 2560x1440+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 608mm x 345mm panning 2560x1440+3840+0
   3840x2160     30.00 +  25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95* 
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94
```

[These](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-envy-15-as100-notebook-pc/12499192/model/13583278/document/c05310214) are technical requirements, and for now here is what I tried :

- Got a monitor `Samsung U28E590D`, which outputs 4k on DP and HDMI2, got an HDMI2 cable but doesnt work
- Tried to handle different scales for both monitors using `xrandr` : `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 1x1 --panning 2560x1440+3840+0 --fb 6400x3560 --right-of eDP-1` not working correctly (got only half of external screen - right one)
- Thinked about buying an HDMI -> Dp converter, but never found one doing HDMI -> DP, only DP -> HDMI
- Tried downscaling my laptop monitor to FullHD resolution, but everything is waaaay to blurry
- Upscaled resolution of external monitor, but capped @30Hz, waaaay too low to work everyday with it.
- Thinked about using usb-c, but apparently usb-c cannot output to a monitor if it's not thunderbolt, which is not..

So I am starting to think that maybe the HDMI output of the laptop only outputs HDMI < 2, which prevents from being able to output 4k@60hz, but could not find out any info about this.

Oh, one last thing, on the monitor product description it says that monitor supports only 4k@60 on dp, while HDMI goes for 30hz, **BUT** found this on [amazon products questions](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx1SZDVMVOQSKZY/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza) (second answer, reported below, relevant part: `3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (HDMI2)`) :

```
Model Name: U28E590D / U24E590D
-----------------------------------------
Synchronization -> Horizontal Frequency
30 - 135 kHz (DisplayPort)
30 - 90 kHz (HDMI1)
30 - 135 kHz (HDMI2)
Synchronization -> Vertical Frequency
56 - 75 Hz (DisplayPort)
24 - 75 Hz (HDMI1/HDMI2)
Optimum Resolution
3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (DisplayPort)
3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz (HDMI1)
3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (HDMI2)
Maximum Resolution
3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (DisplayPort)
3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz (HDMI1)
3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz (HDMI2)
-----------------------------------------
Notes: Both above models are fully FreeSync certified. The DP 1.2a+ port has Adaptive-Sync support, and can be used with AMD's FreeSync variable refresh rate technology. These models also include HDMI v2.0 ports (HDMI2) which support 4k res. @ 60Hz, while the 1st HDMI port (HDMI1) remains only HDMI v1.4ax1. This provides many different input source options.
*****************************************
Model Name: U28D590D (Older Model)
-----------------------------------------
Synchronization -> Horizontal Frequency
30 ~ 134 kHz (DisplayPort)
30 ~ 90 kHz (HDMI1/2)
Synchronization -> Vertical Frequency
56 ~ 75 Hz (DisplayPort)
24 ~ 75 Hz (HDMI)
Optimum Resolution
3840 x 2160 @ 60Hz (DisplayPort)
3840 x 2160 @ 30Hz (HDMI)
Maximum Resolution
3840 x 2160 @ 60Hz (DisplayPort)
3840 x 2160 @ 30Hz (HDMI)
-----------------------------------------
Notes: Older model supports a single DP v1.2 port and two HDMI v1.4 ports limiting 60Hz 4k connectivity to the DP port only
*****************************************
References:
Source for U28E590D data: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201510/20151030173012594/BN46-00481B-Eng.pdf
Press Release: https://news.samsung.com/global/samsung-electronics-new-uhd-monitors-deliver-more-powerful-and-enjoyable-viewing-experience
Source for older model U28D590D data: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201403/20140305101006156/BN46-00410A-Eng.pdf
AMD FreeSync: http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/technologies-gaming/freesync
HDMI: http://www.hdmi.org/index.aspx
DisplayPort: http://www.displayport.org/
*****************************************
```

**disclaimer: this is an amazon answer, not sure how trusted can it be, but it supposes monitor has 2 HDMI (it does): one supporting HDMI <2, other 2+, I tried both and same thing appears on xrandr output**

Any feedback would be apreciated, whether it is on buying another monitor or using xrandr to having a smaller gap between two resolutions, actually having one 3840*2160@60hz and second at 2560*1440@60hz.

Comment: Given how new the laptop is (HP suggests it has an i7-7xxx in it?) I would be surprised if it didnt support HDMI >2. It seems though that the manufacturers may not be fitting the right components in order to fully support the latest standards. This Intel forum page suggests that many people are hitting these restrictions and they believe it to be a manufacturing problem, the graphics chip *should* support it: https://communities.intel.com/thread/114538

Comment: Other parts of that page say that Intel only support 4k@60Hz over DisplayPort...

Comment: see my edits about your last comment, added infos

Comment: according to your link : `Intel CPU only offer UHD 60Hz on Displayport, the HDMI is 1.4 max (UHD 30Hz).` so it will never works on my laptop (and yes got an Intel® Core™ i7-7500U chipset)